# join on cats-effect fiber doesn't raise inner error

Tags: scala-cats, cats-effect, fibers

A cats-effect fiber, once started, a reference kept of it, some other code executed and then rejoined, won't raise the errors that happen inside.

Do you know why `.join` doesn't throw an error and why my application doesn't quit. Why will a thread remain running and the application stays hanging while also hiding the original error?

In my code

```scala
(for {
  startedStreamsFiber <- List(
        stream1,
        stream2,
      ).parTraverse_(_.compile.drain).toResource.start
  _ <- logger.info("Application has started").toResource
  _ <- startedStreamsFiber.join
} yield ()).use_
```

if one of the inner streams raises an error such as

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint ...
```

the application won't fail, but stay on and keep logging:

```
Non-daemon threads currently preventing JVM termination: - 34: Thread[KQueueEventLoopGroup-2-1,10,main]
 -  - 38: Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main]
Non-daemon threads currently preventing JVM termination: - 34: Thread[KQueueEventLoopGroup-2-1,10,main]
 -  - 38: Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main]
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the solution is to use `startedStreamsFiber.joinWithUnit`. Simple as that.
`.join` doesn't have the same error handling as `.joinWith`, `.joinNever` or `.joinWithUnit`. It's the only one that doesn't propagate errors. This way it works and I get the nice stacktrace and the application quits.